# Explain why it is impossible for $G$ to have such Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Explain why it is impossible for $G$ to have one Sylow
> $2$-subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and another Sylow $2$-subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

**My idea**: By the second Sylow theorem we know that the Sylow $p$-subgroups are always conjugate to each other; and thus, they have the same order. So $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ must be conjugate. In other words,  $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ are isomorphic, wich is impossible.

Is this correct?

Comment: "Sylow $p$-subgroups are always conjugate to each other; and thus, they have the same order" - well, they would have the same order even if they weren't conjugate to each other. I think you have the right idea, but I would word it slightly differently: all Sylow $p$-subgroups (for fixed $p$) are conjugate, and conjugation is an automorphism, therefore all Sylow $p$-subgroups (for fixed $p$) are isomorphic. Since $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ are not isomorphic (one is cyclic and the other is not), a group can't have both types as Sylow $2$-subgroups.

Comment: Btw, the assumption that they are *Sylow* subgroups is crucial here. In general, a group can have non-isomorphic subgroups of the same order. E.g. $S_4$ has subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$ and subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. This doesn't contradict anything, since Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$ have order $8$, not $4$.

Comment: Yes, Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugated and hence isomorphic, because conjugation yields a group isomorphism.